# How/where does a generator + motor dissipate heat?

Tags: power, motor, heat, generator, theory

I've got a mystery that I can't wrap my head around.

A generator is generating 1 kW of electric power. The current goes through copper cables to a motor, which is consuming say 950 W of electric power. (It isn't exactly equal to power generated because of resistive losses in the cables.)

I'm assuming a very simple isolated circuit here. So the voltage is never transformed, and nothing else is on our circuit.

If the generator is generating 1 kW, then the current in its windings should be dissipating 1 kW of heat. But if the motor is consuming 950 W, its heat dissipation should be 950 W. Or in other words, total heat dissipation should be 1,950 W.

But that's impossible. We're only generating 1 kW of power. **So I guess my question is, how or where does all this heat get dissipated?** If it's split 50/50 between the generator and motor, I don't understand how the motor can be using 950 W but only dissipating 475 W of heat. Same thing for the generator, 1 kW generated but somehow only dissipating 500 W?

Do the windings of a generator somehow not dissipate heat? Can't imagine that. If it's copper wires then it should have resistive losses like anything else. I suppose an implicit question within this question is, does a generator dissipate heat in the same way as a motor?

Comment: Not all the energy is lost as heat. If it were, then the motor would just be a heater with no mechanical output. What are the efficiencies of the motor and generator?

Comment: Torque x speed also equals watts

Comment: Read the generator's spec. If it's 90% efficient, it's consuming 1111W from some power source, generating 1000W, and dissipating the other 111W (10%) as heat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The motor uses most of the input power to cause motion, not to generate heat.  A 1kW motor that made 1kW of heat from 1kW of electrical power would be a very poor motor - it would more commonly be called a heater.

A motor that consumes 1kW of power transforms a large part of that electrical power into rotation of the shaft.  The rest is wasted as heat.  Your 1kW motor might be 75% efficient.  It transforms 1kW of electrical power into 750W of mechanical power with only 250W wasted as heat.

That 250W of wasted power could be lost in the electical windings of the motor (wire has resistance) or it could be lost in mechanical friction - or a combination of both, and other effects besides.

A generator that produces 1kW of waste heat from 1kW of mechanical power would be pretty crummy.  You want the heat produced (power wasted) to be a small part of the total input power.  I have read that generators can be over 90 percent efficient.  For 1kW of mechanical power in, you would get over 900W of electrical power out with less than 100W wasted as heat in the windings.

---

You are somehow equating the power generated with the power dissipated.

The two are not the same.  A 1kW generator does not dissipate 1kW of power in its coils to produce the 1kW of output.

In the same way, a motor doesn't produce 1kW of heat when fed 1kW of electrical power to produce its mechanical output.

Producing heat is a waste.  It is **not** part of the transformation of electrical energy to mechanical energy.  It is a loss caused by imperfect machines.  If a motor had superconductor windings and no mechanical friction, then it would produce the same amount of mechanical power out as you put electrical power in. It would turn your load and it would **not** get hot.

A generator with superconducting windings and no friction would produce the same electrical output power as the input mechanical input power - and it would **not** get hot.

---

Take your generator/motor combination.

You put in 1100 watts of mechanical power to the generator shaft.  The generator is 90 percent efficient, so it make 1kW of electical power.

That 1kW of electrical power drives the motor.  Assuming a 75 percent efficient motor, it will lose 25 percent (250 watts) as heat and provide 750 watts of mechanical power on its shaft.

- Total loss:  350 watts, split unevenly between generator and motor.
- Total mechanical output power 750 watts at the motor shaft.

Comment: `You are somehow equating the power generated with the power dissipated.` I think you are right, in regards to electrical power. However, I thought I read somewhere that **all** types of power will eventually dissipate as heat: mechanical is stopped by friction, acoustic waves also dissipate as heat. So sadly i probly need thermodynamics to fully answer my question, but this is far enough for electrical things. +1 and ty.

Comment: @DrZ214 the power can go into a number of things.  We could turn water into hydrogen and oxygen, throw a rocket into space, etc., not just make heat.  Heat is probably the most common end point of electricity.